# cPanel seems to be editing my .htaccess files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After changing to a new server and shifting my domain over, my `.htaccess` files seem to have been changed by cPanel and I don't know why.

For instance, what once looked like this:

```
# Route everything via index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Has been changed to this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

And I have no idea why! I'm not great with `.htaccess` files, so can anyone explain what the changes do?

Answer (score 0):

Two conditions are being added to each of your rules to exclude certain URLs from being processed by them. As follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
```

Any URL of the format `/` followed by one or more digits, then a period `.`, then one or more of anything at all, followed by `.cpaneldcv`.

So the most obvious part is the last, and will limit what it affects very much, to only things ending with `.cpaneldcv`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
```

This one is `/` followed by exactly 32 characters, being digits or the uppercase letters A to F, followed by `.txt`. Optionally that can be followed by `Comodo DCV`, which is strange because URLs don't include spaces.

So all it's doing is stopping your rules affecting those. Fairly innocuous.